# crashes when I try to call function from activity class

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception

OK, so I've run into a very strange situation. I'm trying to set up ads in my app, and that hasn't worked yet, and I'm not fully sure why. I've been running into this error. I'm calling a function from my activity in another class that is a bit disconnected, but I do have a reference.  I'm getting this log error. be aware I have taken all actual calls to my ad out, I'm literally calling an empty function.

```
01-19 07:32:54.440: E/AndroidRuntime(13651): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-49013
01-19 07:32:54.440: E/AndroidRuntime(13651): java.lang.IllegalStateException: setAdListener must be called on the main UI thread.
01-19 07:32:54.440: E/AndroidRuntime(13651):    at azy.b(SourceFile:174)
01-19 07:32:54.440: E/AndroidRuntime(13651):    at xq.a(SourceFile:511)
01-19 07:32:54.440: E/AndroidRuntime(13651):    at ya.onTransact(SourceFile:105)
01-19 07:32:54.440: E/AndroidRuntime(13651):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
01-19 07:32:54.440: E/AndroidRuntime(13651):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ac$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
01-19 07:32:54.440: E/AndroidRuntime(13651):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.c(Unknown Source)
01-19 07:32:54.440: E/AndroidRuntime(13651):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.loadAd(Unknown Source)
01-19 07:32:54.440: E/AndroidRuntime(13651):    at net.timepieceent.Pong.DroidPongActivity.loadAndDisplayAd(DroidPongActivity.java:65)
01-19 07:32:54.440: E/AndroidRuntime(13651):    at net.timepieceent.Pong.MainMenu.stateChange(MainMenu.java:363)
01-19 07:32:54.440: E/AndroidRuntime(13651):    at net.timepieceent.Pong.MainMenu.buttonCheck(MainMenu.java:219)
01-19 07:32:54.440: E/AndroidRuntime(13651):    at net.timepieceent.Pong.MainMenu.update(MainMenu.java:151)
01-19 07:32:54.440: E/AndroidRuntime(13651):    at com.badlogic.framework.AndroidFastRenderView.run(AndroidFastRenderView.java:48)
01-19 07:32:54.440: E/AndroidRuntime(13651):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

does anyone have any idea why I might be getting this error? I feel like this is actually the problem I'm having, and not the ads. please help. thank you so much in advance.

EDIT: I've even taken google play services library out and I'm still getting this error. I don't understand why it's saying anything about setAdListener, since I'm not calling it at all.

EDIT: my program is unquestionably glitched. I've deleted the entirety of DroidPongActivity, which should make it so the application doesn't run, but it's still doing exactly the same thing. this is bizarre.

EDIT: thanks everyone. I applied the Runonuithread solution after I fixed my project. Eclipse wasn't installing new code alterations, so I copied the project to another folder, deleted it in eclipse and imported it back in. everything was dandy after that.

I'd close this discussion, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you're doing, the error is saying it should be done on the UI Thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {

      // your code here

  }
});
```

The error is line 65 of your activity. Move that (and perhaps similar code) into the run() method.

Comment: I'm starting to think my whole project is glitched, because there is no line 65, but I'm still getting an error for it. I'm not sure what to do now. thanks for your help.

Comment: It says 65 alright: at net.timepieceent.Pong.DroidPongActivity.loadAndDisplayAd(DroidPongActivity.java:65) Can you post the code for DroidPongActivity?

Comment: I literally removed all code from DroidPongActivity, and it's still running the program like there's code in it. which I could understand, minus that I have actually uninstalled the application and had it reinstalled. I don't know what's going on with my project. I have one more thing to check, then I'll check back here.

Comment: eclipse suggested i hard code "android:allowBackup="true"" into my manifest, could this have something to do with the program refusing to change?

Comment: You could always remove it to find out. To see if your app's code is what you think it is, put Log.d("test test", "test test"); in your Activity's onCreate() and see if you see it in the logs. Or fire a toast, ect.

Comment: I don't know how to fix this. No alterations I'm making are reflecting my launch. I uninstalled the app and restarted eclipse. I don't know what to do about this. does anyone know where an application might get backed up on the device? this is so bizarre.

Comment: this is not the problem I thought I was trying to fix. I'm going to do a search for this problem. sorry everyone. hopefully your responses can help me fix the problem I'm having once I've resolved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you are calling a main UI method in another thread, even having reference, you can not call UI related method directly from another thread.

You can check below link to how to communicate with UI thread
https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: I'll have to read through that once I figure out what's going on with my project.. this error doesn't even make sense anymore. thanks for the help and reference.

Answer (score 0):

From your logcat error it seems that you are trying to do something off the UI thread, That must be done on the UI thread. Do like this,

```
Runnable r = new Runnable () {

    @Override
    public void run() {
       // Do Here whatever you are trying to do
    }
}

runOnUiThread(r);
```

Hope this will resolve your problem, If not please let me know.